# Why are these two events independent?

Tags: probability, independence

I am reading a [solution (#4)](http://people.math.sc.edu/lu/teaching/2012fall_778P/homework3_sol.pdf) to a problem in Spencer and Alon's *The Probabalistic Method*, and I am a bit confused on one part, and it can be basically summed up as this:

Let $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_n$ be real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2=1$, and let $(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\dots,\varepsilon_n)$ be a $\{-1,1\}$ random vector. Let $$X=\sum_{i=1}^j\varepsilon_ia_i \space\space \text{ and } \space\space Y=\sum_{i=j+1}^n\varepsilon_ia_i.$$

At one point, the answer gives
$$\Pr[-1\leq X\leq 0 \text{ and } 0\leq Y\leq1]=\Pr[-1\leq X\leq 0]\cdot\Pr[0\leq Y\leq1],$$

but I don't see how these two events are necessarily independent. Could someone justify this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an important part of the statement here: it is assumed that the $\epsilon_i$ are *independent*.

Note then that $X$ depends only on $\epsilon_1\ldots\epsilon_j$ and $Y$ only on $\epsilon_{j+1}\ldots\epsilon_n$. Since the $\epsilon_i$ are independent and $X$ and $Y$ depend only on separate sets of $\epsilon_i$'s we can conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are also independent.

In case you are wondering about the $a_i$: those are not random variables, just some reals. They thus do not influence the independence. The fact that they add up to 1 does not change that, again since they are not random variables.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!